# Rails/Devise How to redirect to a specific page after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

After `login` and `signup`, I want to redirect the user to a specific page only if the user came from a specific page.

What I have tried to do so far – using `devise`:

1. I added a parameter to a link and checked that parameter in the login page. Using the method `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` from `devise`, I created a conditional to that parameter. If `true`, the page would be redirect to my wanted page

   **Link**

   ```
   <%= link_to "Login before continuing", new_user_session_path(:registration_process => true)
   ```

   **On `ApplicationController.rb`**

   ```
   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if params[:registration_process]
       leads_path  # desired page
    else
      super
    end
   end
   ```

This is not working.

I don't know if using `params` is the best option, since I want to do the same with the sign up page.

Thank you very much. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not a ruby expert, but maybe you can pass in the desired redirect url as a parameter? Then you could redirect to it if it's passed in after every login. Otherwise you would have to add another such configuration for every workflow, and you might have many more in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy! Why not try:

`URI(request.referer).path`  ?

Now you can basically identify the path where you came from.

You can also store the page where you came from in a session. e.g.

```
session[:intended_url] = request.url
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
if resource.class == User && current_user
    user_dashboard_path
else
    super
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should pass your params with session path inside your new_user_session_path form like `url: session_path(resource_name, :registration_process => true)`
after that you can use `if params[:registration_process]`